# Python implementation of ODE system of interconnected Neurons

Tags: python, ode

I have implemented a ODE description of the calcium signaling of neurons as described [in this paper](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3523264).
The approach is relative simple: the ODEs of four states are implemented and solved via `odeint()` or `solve_ivp()` to gain the trajectories of the desired states. Here is my implementation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



class ModelParameters:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0.111
        self.delta = 0.01 
        self.gamma = 5.405 
        self.mu_0 = 0.567 
        self.mu_1 = 0.433 
        self.V_1 = 0.889
        self.k_2 = 0.7 
        self.k_4 = 1.1 
        self.k_p = 0.4 
        self.k_e = 0.06 
        self.k_1 = 1.1 
        self.k_mu = 4 
        self.k_flux = 6 
        self.V_p = 24 
        self.V_e = 20 
        self.alpha_1 = 1
        self.alpha_2 = 2.5
        self.beta = 0.8

        self.epsilon = 0.01

        self.alpha = 1

        self.tau = 2
        self.nu = .6


        self.Q_c = 1 
        self.Q_p = 10 

        # Parameters for impuls
        self.Mdach = 8.333
        self.t_0 = 17 # shall be replaced by the time of the peak of a neighboring neuron
        self.Delta = 0.72
        
        self.addPulse = False
        
    def realization (self): # Realization of parameters by drawing from normal distribution with 20% variance
        self.k_2 =  np.random.normal(self.k_2, self.k_2 * 0.2)
        self.k_4 = np.random.normal(self.k_4, self.k_4 * 0.2) 
        self.k_p = np.random.normal(self.k_p, self.k_p * 0.2) 
        self.k_e = np.random.normal(self.k_e, self.k_e * 0.2) 
        self.k_1 = np.random.normal(self.k_1, self.k_1 * 0.2) 
        self.k_mu = np.random.normal(self.k_mu, self.k_mu * 0.2) 
        self.k_flux = np.random.normal(self.k_flux, self.k_flux * 0.2) 
        
        
class modelNeuron:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params
        
    def heavi(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            return(0)
        elif x >= 0:
            return(1)
    
    def computeDeriv(self, state, t):

        C, C_t, r, P = state
        mp = self.params
        
        taudach = (mp.tau * mp.delta * mp.V_p) / mp.Q_c
        nudach = (mp.nu * mp.Q_c) / (mp.Q_p * mp.delta * mp.V_p)
        betadach = (mp.beta * mp.Q_c) / (mp.delta * mp.V_p)
        
        
        
        # Intermediate variables
        J_in = mp.alpha_1/mp.V_p + mp.alpha_2/mp.V_p * (mp.Q_p * nudach)/betadach
        J_pm = C**2 / ( C**2 + (mp.k_p**2/mp.Q_c**2))
        J_serca = mp.V_e/mp.V_p * (C / (C + (mp.k_e/mp.Q_c)))
        J_release = (
            (mp.k_flux * mp.gamma * mp.Q_c) / (mp.V_p) *
            (mp.mu_0 + mp.mu_1 * ( (P) / (P + ((mp.k_mu) / mp.Q_p)))) *
            r *
            (mp.b + (mp.V_1 * ( (C) / (C + ((mp.k_1) / mp.Q_c) )))) * 
            (C_t - (1 + (1/mp.gamma)) * C)
        )
        
        if mp.addPulse :
            pulseAdded = (mp.Mdach * self.heavi(t - mp.t_0)*self.heavi(mp.t_0 + mp.Delta - t) )
        else:
            pulseAdded = 0
        
        dC_dt = (J_release - J_serca + mp.epsilon * (J_in - J_pm))/mp.epsilon
        dCt_dt = J_in - J_pm
        dr_dt = 1/taudach * ((mp.k_2**2) / (mp.k_2**2 + mp.Q_c**2 * C**2) - r)
        dP_dt = nudach * (1- ((mp.alpha) / 1 + ((mp.Q_c * C) / (mp.k_4)))) - betadach * P + pulseAdded
                
               
        deriv = [dC_dt, dCt_dt, dr_dt, dP_dt]
        return deriv
```

To use this two classes to simulate five neurons one can use:

```
random_values = np.random.uniform(low=[0, 1], high=[0.7, 3], size=(5, 2))

# Create an array with the same last two elements for all 5 arrays
common_values = np.array(([0.8742206 , -0.00888252], [0.8742206 , -0.00888252], [0.8742206 , -0.00888252], [0.8742206 , -0.00888252], [0.8742206 , -0.00888252]))

# Combine the random values and common values for each inner array
initials = np.column_stack((random_values, common_values))
allResults = []
Tmax = 50
dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0,Tmax,dt)
parList = []
for _ in range(5) :
    pars = ModelParameters()
    pars.realization()
    parList.append(pars)
for i, pars in enumerate(parList):
    initial = initials[i] 
    mySys = modelNeuron(pars)
    allResults.append(odeint(mySys.computeDeriv, initial, t))

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=500)

for i in range(5) :
    plt.subplot(10,1,i+1)
    plt.plot(t, allResults[i][:,0], label=f'Neuron {i + 1}')
    
plt.show()
```

As you can see, it is already implemented that an external pulse at t_0 (here: 17) is added to the dynamic of P. What I want now, is that if two neurons are connected, firing of neuron A leads to such a pulse of neuron B. The problem is, that the pulse time t_0 for neuron B depends on the dynamic of neuron A, which is not a priori given.

Is it possible to change the `computeDeriv()` function in such a way, that in the progress of integration via `odeint()` or `solve_ivp()` the peaks times of neuron A are identified and passed to neuron B?